# Response rows: [ anonymous { today: 2017-08-14T00:08:52.643Z } ] - Node version v8.2.1

Tags: node.js, anonymous-function, node-postgres

i'm working with node-postgres and try to make the first example

And create a Class called Postgres with a method today

```
const conn = new pg.Pool({
  user: 'user',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'test',
  password: 'pass',
  port: 5432,
});

class Postgres {
   today() {
    conn.query("SELECT NOW() as today",(err,res)=>{
        if (err) throw err
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(res.rows[0]));
            return JSON.stringify(res.rows[0]);
            conn.end();
    })

    }
}
```

The result is that rows: [ anonymous { today: 2017-08-14T00:08:52.643Z } ] and try with JSON.stringify(res.rows[0]) but not working i can't get the field

```
Result {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 1,
  oid: NaN,
  rows: [ anonymous { today: 2017-08-14T00:08:52.643Z } ],
  fields:
   [ Field {
       name: 'today',
       tableID: 0,
       columnID: 0,
       dataTypeID: 1184,
       dataTypeSize: 8,
       dataTypeModifier: -1,
       format: 'text' } ],
  _parsers: [ [Function: parseDate] ],
  RowCtor: [Function: anonymous],
  rowAsArray: false,
  _getTypeParser: [Function: bound ] }
```

Any sugestion be apreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try `res.rows[0].today` this will work!